# Replace the default orange site icon

Tags: css, site, picture

I am using a CSS page to stylize a site and subequent pages from it. I've successfully added my icon to the top-left of the site/pages but cannot figure out how to remove the default orange SP icon.

[image]

The orange icon is on top and you can see my icon peeking out the bottom-right from behind it.

I have already tried `#ctl00_onetidHeadbnnr2{display:none;}` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: are you talking about the favIcon? the image showing the location of the Site image?

Comment: This is the default icon that displays on the site by the breadcrumb navigation.

Comment: navigation up icon, folder image?

Comment: I dont think I am understanding your questions. This has nothing to do with the navigation up icon or the favicon (which also uses the same image). This orange icon is the default icon (#ctl00_onetidHeadbnnr2) on a site, next to the site's breadcrumb navigation, when it is created. In this case, I have made it larger since the logo I am using is larger. I added my own logo to the site (its under the orange icon) using CSS. However, I cannot seem to remove the default icon that is still on top.

Comment: oh i see, so this is logo, why not change it from the site settings...http://sharepointadam.com/2009/12/17/how-to-change-the-site-logo-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: I tried changing it under the site settings> Edit page but it wasnt inheriting to everything so i decided to just attach my CSS to the masterpage but it wasnt overriding the default icon. I was trying to avoid editing the masterpage but did so and just changed the siteIcon URL to the icon I wanted to use.